# Graph level curves and use arrows to show gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My textbook has this question:

> Find grad f. Graph some level curves f = const. Indicate $\nabla{f}$ by arrows at some points of these curves.

The function is $(x+1)(2y-1)$

$\nabla{f} = [2y-1, 2x+2]$

which I obtained by taking the partial derivatives of x and y.

What is a level curve? What am I drawing exactly? Can someone explain this to me? My textbook does not explain what to do here.

Comment: A level curve is the set of points (x,y) such that f(x,y)=c for a fixed constant c.

Comment: If you want to draw some, consider drawing the curves given by (x+1)(2y-1)=c for c=1, -1, 0, ...

Comment: I guarantee you that the textbook explains what a level curve is and the relationship of the gradient to it.

Comment: It does not, here is the definition of level curve they provide: "first draw a few level curves f(x, y)  const of f(x, y), then parallel lineal elements along each such curve (which is also called an isocline, meaning a curve of equal inclination), and finally draw approximation curves fit to the lineal elements."  The book is by kreyszig. I don't understand what that means because as I plug in different level x and y, I get a different c

Comment: First several [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=level+curve) hits explain in detail (with pictures) what a level curve is. You select $c$ first, than connect the $(x,y)$ pints that verify the equation.

Comment: Care to show me an example?